# Prove for any real constants $x, y$ where $y > 0$ that $(n+7x)^y = Θ(n^y)$

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

So I need to prove that for any real constants $x$ and $y$, where $y > 0$, $(n+7x)^y = Θ(n^y)$.

To prove that it is a big Theta I need to prove both that it is big O and Big Omega. So I prove that it is a big O in the following way:

Using Newton's binomial theorem

$(n+7x)^y = n^y + n^{y-1}*(7x)*y + n^{y-2}*(7x)^2(y(y-1)) + ... + (7x)^y$.

For Big O I need to estimate above hence I replace every power of n with $n^y$ as I estimate from above and got

$(n+7x)^y <= n^y + n^y*(7x)*y + n^y*(7x)^2(y(y-1)) + ... + (7x)^y$

$ \implies (n+7x)^y <= n^y(1 + (7x)*y + (7x)^2(y(y-1)) + ... + (7x)^y)$.

Now we have coefficient $(1 + (7x)*y + (7x)^2(y(y-1)) + ... + (7x)^y)$ for n on right hand side.

Let's denote that by $A \implies c(n+7x)^y <= An^y $. I can take $c = A+1$ and will obtain that $(n+7x)^y <= n^y$ for all $n>=1$.

Now I want to prove that there exists $c_2$ such that

$c_2n^y \Leftarrow (n+7x)^y$.

Can anyone help me with the last part?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest way, that will simplify both directions:
$$(n+7x)^y = n^y\left(1+\frac{7x}{n}  \right)^y \sim n^y$$
where  $f\sim g$ we understand as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1$. Now it's enough to use property $f\sim g \Rightarrow f=\Theta(g)$.

As addition, how to obtain exactly left side inequality you asked about: from written limit we have
$$\left| \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}-1 \right|<\varepsilon $$
$$1-\varepsilon < \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < 1+\varepsilon$$
$$(1-\varepsilon)g(n)< f(n) < (1+\varepsilon)g(n)$$
Now left side is what you wanted, in appropriate conditions.